# Accept Year Values in TextBox C#

Tags: c#, textbox

I am a first-timer here. Not aware of the rules exactly.

My question is this: I have a TextBox and I want this TextBox to accept years only. The format of the text must be like 2012-2013

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you creating a Win-form application?

Comment: Here you can use regular expression.

Comment: `"I am a first-timer here. Not aware of the rules exactly.`" Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should probably take the [**tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and browse through the [**help center**](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before asking. We ask that questions show effort (and the code you've tried, in most cases), which this question doesn't really do.

Comment: Use drop down with values: 2012-2013, 2013-2014, 2014-2015....etc

Comment: Well a good rule to follow is to always show what you have tried so far. The majority of us here will avoid doing all the work for you, and your question will likely get downvoted for showing a lack of effort on your part

Comment: You can extend your Text box control. e.g. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3c2010d9-93db-4cd8-8160-eee4343c7fea/extending-textbox-control?forum=csharplanguage

Comment: @Saket: I imagine the requirement is to allow for different ranges. For example, `"2010-2014"`. The combination of items for a drop down would be unusable

Comment: Perhaps [`MaskedTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox.aspx) can do this?

Comment: @user2636787: You need to specify your requirements more clearly. You also need to add the code you have used (your efforts).

Comment: I respect your comments and I will definitely put in more efforts from next time

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack...

Here is a Regular expression that should work for you

```
^([0-9]{4})[./-]+([0-9]{4})$ //Results in 2012-2013 or 2012/2013
```

And as for adding it to your app, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx) is an article that could help you.

Comment: Hey thanks, I didn't expect great answers so quick. I will definitely try this!

Answer (score 0):

Put this regex  in your code

> ^[12][0-9]{3}$